# Number cubes with consecutive line sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

This is barely of research interest, but I'd classify it as a curiosity with connections to combinatorics.

The problem is to place integers in an $n \times n \times n$ array so that all $3n^2$ line sums are consecutive integers.

I only have ad-hoc solutions for $n = 2,3,5,7$, and a product construction.
For instance, $n = 2$ admits the solution
$\left[{\begin{array}{cc}
(0,4) & (0,6) \\
(1,4) & (2,5) \\
\end{array}}\right]$, and solutions for $n_1,n_2$ can be easily 'shifted' and 'composed' (sort of like a Kronecker product).

Does anyone notice a construction general enough to work, say, for all primes?  Related ideas are welcome too.

Comment: Remark:  The two-dimensional version is easy.  In this case, $n$ must be even (or $n=1$).  So simply let $A$ be the first layer of the above three-dim solution for $n=2$, which has line sums 0,1,2,3; then for general $n \times n$, form a block diagonal matrix using $A$, $A+2J$, $A+4J$, $\dots$, $A+(n-2)J$.